# Issue with detecting if a div exists -> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect if a div exists so that I can change its aria-label however I seem to be having a syntax error based on the other examples I've looked at. If anyone can point me in the right direction if would be a great help.

```
const div = document.querySelector('div');
if (div.classList.contains('hamburger hamburger--squeeze is-active')) {
  echo "This works";
}
```

Comment: "echo" is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: you can use console.log() instead of echo

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/tuxbLp0m/

Comment: I wonder if i'll ever find someone, who will explain to me, why a question, which writes obviously invalid syntax, which any IDE will detect, and is entirely about "i get a syntax error, why?", "shows research effort, is useful and clear".

Comment: @ASDFGerte That's the eternal mystery of SO I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

```
const div = document.querySelector('div');
if (div.classList.contains('hamburger hamburger--squeeze is-active')) {
  console.log("This works");
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Working on too many different things XML, XSL, PHP, JS, APIs. I was bound to toss them in a blender. Thank you!